# Please how can I solve useMutation

Tags: react-query

I want to add a user to database using react-query useMutation but I am having this error with the library. Please can anybody help me out. Here is my code.

TypeError: Object is not a function:

````
import { addStaff } from "./async";
function Navbar() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
 
  const [mutateAdd] = useMutation(addStaff, {
    onSuccess: () => console.log("User successfully added"),
  });

  const onAdd = () => {
    mutateAdd({ text: inputRef.current.value });
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div></div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", marginLeft: 40 }}>
        <Input placeholder="start typing..." ref={inputRef} />
        <Button onClick={onAdd}>Invite Staff</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Are you using Apollo?

Comment: No, am using react-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v3, `useMutation` does not return an array but an object. See the migration guide: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#usemutation-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-an-array

So you likely want:

```
const { mutate } = useMutation(addStaff, {
    onSuccess: () => console.log("User successfully added"),
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This really solved my problem. I was using mutateAdd instead of mutate.